# How to equally space items of a uniform grid only "internally" (see image)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm triyng to solve a tricky situation.
I have my listbox constrained into grid.rowdefinition and grid.column definition;
this listbox is using a UniformGrid as the ItemsPanel. The effect I want to obtain is that the items of this listbox would be shown equally spaced, but only in the internal side of the ItemsPanel, and not also on the outside. In the image the black border is the border of the listbox. If the items were arranged statically, i could use Margin alternatively setting the right, bottom and the left,top margins. But they are dinamically arranged using Data Binding. I don't have Idea how to obtain this layout.
As additional information I can tell you that the uniformGrid will always show 8 items, even if they are dinamically arranged.

[image]

Do you have any idea?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here would be a hacky solution using negative margins:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="12345678" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" ClipToBounds="True">
                <!-- Cut off the outer 10 pixels -->
                <ScrollViewer  Margin="-10">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- Might want to port some selection triggers from the default template -->
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <!-- Default margin -->
                        <ContentPresenter  Margin="10"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Width="100">
                <Image Source="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c35af79e54306caedad37141f13de30c?s=128&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Good! It works, at some moment I've tried something similar but this is good. Now I need to get it working at different resolutions :/

Answer (score -1):

try using ItemControl as container and Stretch="UniformToFill" property in image class to resolve your issue:

```
 <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableImages}">              
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=.}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The asker seems to want to add margin to the objects, but not on the "outer edges".